# How to save the state of the only Activity in an Android app when the back button is pressed?

Tags: android, state

I'm making an app that has just one Activity. When I press the Home or Recent Apps button, the state is correctly saved and when I go back to the app everything is there. When I press the Back button and return to the app later, `savedInstanceState` is always null in `onCreate`. I've read that the state is not saved when the back button is pressed, but this seems unintuitive in my case considering that the back and home buttons are equally valid ways to leave the app in the user's eyes, until they try and go back to what they were doing. Is there no way to save state when the back button is pressed?

If I must do some persistent storage, then:

a) How do I override the back button behaviour to make it save the app when back is pressed, and

b) Can I persistently save a Bundle somehow so that I don't have to duplicate the code for state saving?

Comment: Backing out of an app actually terminates the application. Using Home or Recent Apps just hides the application. You'll have to store your data if you want it to remember.

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) I think take a look at it. It will help you solving your problem

Comment: But then I have to duplicate all my code that saves to a Bundle when I just hide the app.

Comment: back-button doesn't hide it terminates... you restore your bundle in onrestoreinstancestate and you load your SharedPreferences in onCreate... oncreate is only called once onrestoreinstancestate gets always called also when you resume an application

Comment: I'm not worried about inefficiency or wasted work I'm worried about having essentially the same code in more than one place. It's bad programming practice and leads to bugs.

Comment: take a look at the Android Lifecycle, this is how it works... or you can drop the bundle and load the values stored in the SharedPreferences in the onresume method, this way they will be loaded in both situation when the activity is resumed or when it is first created

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but my understanding is that savedInstanceState only saves your data when you change your device orientation, but as soon as you click back button, your activity is destroyed. In order to save your data when back button is pressed, you could save your data by using SharePreferences or you could use singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html take a look at an activity lifecycle first. Sounds to me like you need to override the ondestroy method and persist your stuff.you can use a bundle for simple stuff but complex stuff it's best to use parcel.
The oncreate method should check stuff to see if it's null